# Finding fragment dynamically in Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Unless there is some way for the fragment to capturing the volume button click I was looking into this type of approach.

I have any one of several `Fragments` that could be `committed` at any one time. In the main `Activity` I am capturing the volume button `up/down` click. I need some way for the `main Activity` to tell the `Fragment` the `volume button` was `clicked`.

I have [read communicating with Other Fragments](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) and was wondering if I could `dynamically` initiate a `Fragment`.

```
ArticleFragment articleFrag = (ArticleFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.article_fragment);
```

In the above example I need to some how replace `ArticleFragment` with a `String` value and run it through some type of `method` that would `return` the needed `Fragment`.

Otherwise I create a `method` for each possible `fragment` in the main `Activity` and when the `volume button` is `clicked` I pass through a `switch` that determines the correct method to call.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: You can also use :- **fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(TAG);**

Comment: @ldce In my SomeFragment method I setTag to SomeFragment.
`mRootview.setTag("SomeFragment");`

In my main Activity I tried access it like this
`Fragment frag2 = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("SomeTag");`

frag2 is null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add the fragments, if you add them with a tag e.g.

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.the_view_into_which_the_fragment_goes, the_fragment, "tag").commit();'
```

You can later find the tagged fragment with something like

```
the_fragment_type frag = (the_fragment_type)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("tag")
```

or if you want to just use one method:

```
((the_fragment_type)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("tag")).do_the_thing()
```